Where to find messages reported by users in Microsoft Team. ChatMessagePolicyViolationPolicyTip C#
With the help of "ChatMessagePolicyViolationPolicyTip" class I block the messages of a particular user. Now this user reported this message to admin.
Now in Microsoft team's admin center, where can I find and approve this message?
I used below C# code to block chat message:
ChatMessage updatedMessage = new ChatMessage();
 updatedMessage.PolicyViolation = new ChatMessagePolicyViolation()
 {
 PolicyTip = new ChatMessagePolicyViolationPolicyTip()
 {
     GeneralText = "Custom Text to block message",
     MatchedConditionDescriptions = new List<string>() { "Credit Card Number" }
 },
 DlpAction = ChatMessagePolicyViolationDlpActionTypes.BlockAccess,
 VerdictDetails = ChatMessagePolicyViolationVerdictDetailsTypes.AllowFalsePositiveOverride
 };
var result1 = graphClient.Chats[chatId].Messages[messageId].PatchAsync(updatedMessage).Result;


This issue is being tracked here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1791184/where-to-find-messages-reported-by-users-in-micros. Please follow above thread for further updates. Thank you.
